Can someone explain how this H-bridge works?
I am trying to build this circuit so I can control a DC motor using an AVR chip as a brushed speed controller.
https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/hip4081a-datasheet

On page 3 of that datasheet is the example circuit I am trying to construct on a breadboard.
My question is about the H-bridge portion.
From what I understand, if I use the HIP4081A I can use four N-channel MOSFETs for the bridge. If you look closely at the diagram the transistors on the right side mirror the transistors on the left side, which means on the left the drain is connected to voltage and on the right the source is connected to voltage.
I don't understand how this works. Am I just misunderstanding the diagram?


I dont understand how this works? Am I just misunderstanding the
diagram?


Source: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/hip4081a-datasheet (With mods)
One problem you will have is implementing this on a breadboard, it's not advisable to use a breadboard. Most breadboards only support ~1A, if you are doing anything above this the circuit isn't going to function well. Also consider the cross capacitance between rows of the breadboard. Use solder perfboard with large (beefy) traces.

I was planning to use a very large resistor as the load just to test the full circuit. I was planning to limit the power supply output to a little less than 1A. Do you think this would be dangerous? I am very new to this stuff and still learning.

Depends on how you limit the supply

I meant turn the max amp out to about 1A. It is a programmable AC->DC power supply

@yemista It's fine, but use generous gate resistors to make sure it's slowed down to avoid making big current or voltage spikes. Probably over 100Ω, but how much depends on how tight the layout is and how small and fast the transistors are.

You should study the difference between common-source and common-drain (also known as "source-follower"). Here's an answer explaining the differences.
The distinctions of interest here are:

Common-source inverts, common-drain does not. This dictates the phase of the gate signals with respect to each other.

The common-drain (upper) transistor requires a gate potential far exceeding the bridge's positive supply, to be fully switched on. This requires bootstrapping, or some other source of higher potential than the drain.


Keep in mind that a MOSFET's on/off state is determined by the potential difference between its gate and source, \$V_{GS}=V_G-V_S\$, which is only indirectly related to absolute gate potential \$V_G\$ (with respect to ground, 0V).

Majority carriers flow from source to drain which, in an N-channel MOSFET, means that current flows from drain to source. These transistors are connected correctly for H-bridge operation: controlling the flow of current through the load by turning on "diagonally" opposed pairs (e.g. top left/bottom right).

